# How to convert from recursive algorithm to iterative

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, recursion

How do I convert following `recursive` algorithm to `iterative`

```
DFS-Visit(U)
    color[u] = GREY 
    d[u]  =time
    time = time + 1
    for each v = Adj[u] do 
        if color[v] = WHITE
            then p[v] = u
                DFS-Visit(v)
    color[u] = BLACK
    f[u] = time
    time = time + 1
```

Comment: What have you tried? There have been a number of similar questions on StackOverflow recently. Is it university exam time soon?

Comment: Dynamic Programming ?? You can start from the smaller sub problems and proceed for the bigger ones.

Comment: @Cameron: You are right: http://people.csail.mit.edu/thies/6.046-web/recitation9.txt

Comment: @Avinash: Asking people to do your homework for you is frowned upon on StackOverflow. You might want to consider doing your own work.

Comment: @All: This is not a homework, I am trying to learn and write graph library ( http://code.google.com/p/graphplusplus/source/browse/Graph/src/Graph.h ) , During reading DFS fro CLRS, I thought recursive options would not be great.

Comment: You could have done http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+convert+recursive+to+iterative and got the same answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE stack to save the state instead..of calling it recursively

this might help you : http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~pnguyen/251F09/DFS.pdf